# How was Poe transferred to Harlan's World?

Tags: altered-carbon

In season 1 of the Netflix series "Altered Carbon", protagonist Takeshi Kovacs teams up with an AI/hologram who calls himself Poe and who supports Takeshi through his quest.

At the beginning of season 2, we see Kovacs carrying Poe around in what must be a small portable computer that is capable of projecting a holographic representation of Poe. Shortly after, Kovacs's mind gets needlecast to another planet, Harlan's World, where it is "resleeved" into a new body. And somehow, he *still* or *again* has a portable computer that hosts Poe and that is able to project a holographic representation of him (and actually, of his entire hotel).

**How did Poe get to Harlan's World? Did I miss anything?**

Comment: I am even more curious about how Poe's hotel ended up on Harlan's world.  Poe himself is data that could have been transmitted. The hotel is a physical building, I thought.

Comment: @Dima: The hotel *building* is physical, but there seemed to be a scene where Kovacs entered an empty warehouse or something, activated some device (apparently the one that Poe himself is stored on?) and the interior of the hotel would form from what looked like dust. And given that Kovacs can lean on the reception desk, the hotel interior appears to be physical. I found that quite confusing; where could Kovacs have gotten such an omnipotent device from after arriving and basically being on the run right away?

Comment: The hotel decor, fittings, etc. including Poe's construct body (notice he handles physical things like the post-it notes that others can touch) are all formed out of nano-dust that is present in the hotel (presumably from its previous usage).  You can see the dust start taking form after Kovacs downloads Poe into the hotel's system.  Everything about the hotel is constructed by Poe, so it's stored in his image.

Comment: Note that Poe traveling with Kovacs is a difference in the TV series from the books.  Presumably it was felt that it was required to create some continuity between the seasons.  My guess is that they handwaved transmitting the AI in the same way that DHF is needlecast; it doesn't seem unreasonable, it just didn't happen that way in the books.

Comment: @DavidW: Ah, so it's supposed to be physical indeed. I wonder whether this concept was a part of season 1 already, that could have made some things a bit easier. Leaves the question how Kovacs gets his hand on a nano-dust manipulation device - is that a standard thing in-universe? If the operational rifles in the hotel from season 1 and large objects like the elevator were formed from nano-dust, as well, such a device would be immensely powerful.

Comment: @DavidW: Oh, it's fully comprehensible that someone else could have been needlecast to Harlan's World alongside Kovacs. But Kovacs didn't travel out of his own will; he was shot and then needlecast - would whoever did that be thoughtful enough to co-transfer Kovacs' AI friend along with him and provide a suitable portable device at the receiving end? Doubtful. That made the story quite confusing to me.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper The "nanodust" thing was also an invention of the show; probably because it plays better to have a human actor for the AI instead of just an image in a screen.  And in the book the guns in the hotel were *actual* guns.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simple, he chose the job. He told Alexis for his AI to be Transmited to Harlen, and had conditions like the mirror, probably he requested for the device to be present when awaken. [image: Kovacs tells Alexis about his AI to be transmited]! They got his dead sleeve, got his belongings and took them to Alexis in Harlen, besided that the boubty hunter is from Harlen. Netflix blocks the image in screenshots. The hotel is just a projection by Poe, and the nano-dust.

Comment: Great answer! With evidence too.